# Capturing an hlist's ToList evidence as an implicit class parameter

Tags: scala, shapeless, hlist

I'm trying to use shapeless's hlist to construct introspectable URL templates, but I'm having trouble with traversing my HList. The following doesn't compile:

```
import shapeless.{::, HList, HNil}
import shapeless.LUBConstraint._
import shapeless.ops.hlist.ToTraversable._

import scala.util.Try
import shapeless.ops.hlist._

object Path {
  def /(s: String) = Path(PathLiteral(s) :: HNil)

  def param[T](name: String) = PathParameter(name)
}


sealed trait PathSegment[+T]
case class PathLiteral(value: String) extends PathSegment[String]
case class PathParameter[+T](name: String) extends PathSegment[T]


case class Path[L <: HList : <<:[PathSegment[_]]#λ](segments: L)
                                                   (implicit ev: ToList[L, PathSegment[_]])
{
  def /(literal: String) = Path(PathLiteral(literal) :: segments)

  def /[T](param: PathParameter[T]) = Path(param :: segments)

  override def toString: String = s"Path(${segments.toList.reverse})"
}

object Test extends App {

  import Path.param
  val myPath = Path / "v1" / "pets" / param[String]("name") / "pictures"
  println(myPath)

}
```

It seems to me like the `ToTraversable._` import covers the HNil case and the case of having the tail of an HList and a new head with the same Least Upper Bound. Obviously I'm either missing an import or misunderstanding everything.

I'm not sure if caching the evidence in the class as an implicit parameter is kosher; I'm doing it because

1. I don't want hlist details to leak into the external API
2. I need it for a nice toString

Comment: what's the problem?

Comment: It doesn't compile

Answer (score 0):

The reason this doesn't work is the implicit which can prove:

`ToList[PathLiteral :: L, PathSegment[_]]` given

- `ToList[L, PathSegment[L]]`
- `L <: HList`

is this implicit def's type signature from hlists.scala:

```
implicit def hlistToTraversable[H1, H2, T <: HList, LubT, Lub0, M[_]]
  (implicit
    tttvs  : Aux[H2 :: T, M, LubT],
    u      : Lub[H1, LubT, Lub0],
    cbf    : CanBuildFrom[M[Lub0], Lub0, M[Lub0]]) : Aux[H1 :: H2 :: T, M, Lub0]
```

actually needs to know the type of the head of the list as well as the new item (`H1` and `H2`), so it can't be constructed from what's available inside my class.

### Some workarounds:

- build List manually alongside the HList

  ```
  case class Path[L <: HList](segments: L, segmentsList: List[PathSegment[_]]) {
    def /(literal: String) = Path(PathLiteral(literal) :: segments, PathLiteral(literal) :: segmentsList)
    def /[T](param: PathParameter[T]) = Path(param :: segments, param :: segmentsList)
    override def toString: String = s"Path(${segmentsList.reverse})"
  }
  ```
- push implicit parameters out to Path's methods

  ```
  def printPath[L <: HList](path: Path[L])
                           (implicit ev: ToList[L, PathSegment[_]]) =
  path.segments.toList.reverse.collect {
    case PathLiteral(value) => URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8")
    case PathParameter(name) => s"<$name>"
  }.mkString("/")

  printPath(Path / "v1" / "pets"  / param[String]("name") / "pictures")
  // v1/pets/<name>/pictures
  ```